# Installing pip for python 3.5

Tags: python3, pip

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and it had python 3.6.5 by default.
I wanted python 3.5.2 for a project so I downloaded it alongside python3.6, but now the problem is I can't download pip for python 3.5.2 .
It shows this error when I try to download it using

```
python3.5 -m ensurepip --default-pip
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 8.1.1 requires SSL/TLS
```

and when I try to install it using `get-pip.py`, it shows error

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

How do I fix this issue?

I have working pip installed for python3.6 an need a pip for python 3.5.2 .

Answer (score 1):

Per your error message, I think you just need to install python-openssl:

```
sudo apt install python-openssl
```

If the above does not work, you might be able to install for 3.5 via the python shell:

```
$ python3.5
```

And then from the python shell:

```
import ssl
```

If that doesn't work, you need to recompile python 3.5 with ssl support. Start by installing openssl:

```
sudo apt install openssl openssl-dev
```

Then inside your source directory, you need to enable ssl by editing Modules/Setup.dist:

```
nano Modules/Setup.dist
```

Search (ctrl+w) for ssl and uncomment (remove #) from the following line:

```
#SSL=/usr/local/ssl
```

It will look like this when you are done:

```
_socket socketmodule.c

# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
SSL=/usr/local/openssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
-DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
-L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Then you can just compile and install:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: I installed openssl but I am still getting the same error when installing pip for python 3.5.2.